# Php page with slash parameter

Tags: php, url, slash

recently I have noticed that on some of my php webpages it is possible to add a *slash* (/) at the end of URL and write some text, which somehow modifies the page, e.g. assume address (just address example, not available online)

```
http://mypage.com/index.php
```

i typed something like

```
http://mypage.com/index.php/arbitrary_text
```

which causes the page to load with correct source code, but fails to load scripts, styles and images placed on same server (images whose source is outside the server load properly). I have seen this use of this type of address e.g. in CodeIgniter, which loads webpages using the parameters behind slash. However, i use no kind of this project and no htaccess file (and no php code), which would use and proccess such type of address, **so the mystery for me is why do the parameters behind slash (in php page) load without styles, images and scritps, and somewhere the errors occur? Why does this happen?** (I have tested in Chrome and Firefox, latest versions, Chrome shows *broken images* place holder, Firefox doesn't show any image) I have never seen this behaviour before. Could someone explain it (or navigate me through links, etc.)?!

For better imagination: this is a webpage with address of type *mypage.com/gallery.php*

[image: Correct loading of a page]

and this one with address of type *mypage.com/gallery.php/xyz* (just address example, not available online)

[image: URL address with slash]

Comment: it's `PATH_INFO`. look it up in the http spec

Comment: The images/scripts/etc don't load because you are using relative urls for your external files. The browser will think the `index.php` is a folder and so it will request files from the server as `/index.php/images/test.png`. It wouldn't be hard to put something in the top of your php pages to detect it and redirect to the same page without the path info. Or just turn off path_info in your apache config.

Comment: thank you very much. I had no idea where to search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in comments, it is caused by PATH_INFO.